# problems on switching DNS on HA environment

Tags: mysql, dns, redis, high-availability

When I use `DNS server` + `redis/mysql master/slave` as a HA deployment,I found there are two problems:

1. When `redis/mysql` master fails, I promote slave to be new master (`sentinel` for `redis` and `mha` for `mysql`),the domain name change maybe lag  due to the existence of DNS cache, but we can less the DNS ttl or turn off the `nscd` service.
2. Long-live connections maybe keep connecting to the old master (if the connection is not re-connected),this cause problems.

My thought:

After changing the domain name to the new master ip address, we need to kill all existing connections (clients will be re-connect and connect to the new master) or power off the orignal master.

Is there any better ways?

Answer (score 1):

If the two nodes are in the same datacenter, you could user VIP (Virtual IP) , and then move the VIP to master using [corosync](http://linuxlasse.net/linux/howtos/Pacemaker_and_Corosync_HA_-_2_Node_setup), its almost "instantaneous" failover.

If the nodes are in two different datacenters, I think you can use [ProxySQL](https://github.com/sysown/proxysql), I havn't tested ProxySQL yet though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately i can't use VIP(as the cloud service provider not support build VIP on virtual machines). Finally i use a proxy like front end to do a mandatory re-connect after the master ip changes.